# Does not work java script for more than one element

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to use javascript Id for some DropDownListFor in a same view in my MVC project. But it works just for one of them. What do I need to do to solve my problem?

Code in a view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MemberInstance.MemberType_Id, new SelectList(Model.MemberTypeList, "Id", "Title"), new { @id = "demo-select2-1", @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SurgeryInstance.SurgeryType_Id, new SelectList(Model.SurgeryTypeList, "Id", "SurgeryTitle"), new { @id = "demo-select2-1", @class = "form-control" })
```

This just work for first DropDownListFor and not the others.

Comment: [Id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)'s are for unique elements. You should use a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: Please describe more about using a class

Comment: That was just a simple idea based on what I understood from your question. But your question isn't clear at all to me. I'd recommend you to edit it adding some (well formatted) code and better explaining exactly your problem to make it easier for us to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly I found java script Part with id = "demo-select2-1" in theme's scripts then I redefine same function with New Name and use new id in other DropDownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MemberInstance.MemberType_Id, new SelectList(Model.MemberTypeList, "Id", "Title"), new { @id = "demo-select2-1", @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SurgeryInstance.SurgeryType_Id, new SelectList(Model.SurgeryTypeList, "Id", "SurgeryTitle"), new { @id = "demo-select2-a", @class = "form-control" })
```

and also java script function is

```
function r() {
    var b = a("#demo-select2-1");
    b.select2({
        dir: "rtl"
    })
}
```

and my new function is

```
function r1() {
    var b = a("#demo-select2-a");
    b.select2({
        dir: "rtl"
    })
}
```

also I can use it for multiple elements with same way

Answer (score 0):

To be able to apply to several elements you must use a class in this case `Select2Demo`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.First,new SelectList(Model.MemberTypeList, "Id", "Title"), new {@class="Select2Demo"} )

@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Second,new SelectList(Model.MemberTypeList, "Id", "Title"), new {@class="Select2Demo"} )

@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Third,new SelectList(Model.MemberTypeList, "Id", "Title"), new {@class="Select2Demo"} )
```

Selct2

```
$(".Select2Demo").select2({ placeholder: "Select a member" });
```